# Pydev debug project on unmapped network drive duplicates the file

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I opened a project on an unmapped network drive: "\\pc1\dev\my_proj". When I try to debug it, upon hitting the breakpoint the eclipse opens a duplicate of the file instead of the file already opened. Then the 2 files get their path written next to their name in the editor, and the paths are identical instead of that one starts with capital letters:
Path 1: "\pc1\dev\my_proj"
Path 2: "\PC1\dev\my_proj".
The breakpoint is shown on the path 1, wheres the debug marker is shown on the path 2 new duplicate. Also the new path 2 seems to not be belonging to the project like path 1, and eclipse considers it as an external opened file.

Why does it happen only on unmapped projects? And how can I stop it?

I use eclipse Neon.3 and pydev 5.7.

EDIT:
I've checked your advice @fabio, it seems to be happening because:

new Path("A") == new Path("a")

Equals false. And for some reason I couldnt figure out, all files opened by the Pydev Package Explorer have their first path segment in uppercase

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's some issue in that the file is found with a path with one case inside of Python and then later with another case inside PyDev.

Can you post a screenshot and say which is the case found inside PyDev and which is the case found when stepping in the editor?

-- as a note, if you'd be willing to spend some time to itch your own itch, you can get the PyDev code (http://www.pydev.org/developers.html) and inspect what happens under a debugger in `org.python.pydev.editorinput.PySourceLocatorBase` -- probably needs some additional logic somewhere when on windows to consider paths that don't have the same case to be the same...

Comment: I figured out the a solution, but it requires a fix in org.python.pydev.debug.model.XMLUtils: on the function "startFrame" when you get the file absolute path, you should change the first path segment to upper case. That would fix this problem.